# Drupal cronjob from couchbase to MySql not working

Tags: mysql, drupal, cron, couchbase, php-5.6

**I am trying to perform a sync from Couchbase Server to MySql with Drupal cronjob**

I am trying to sync documents from Couchbase to MySql but I am not able to do so
The above operation is taking place with a cronjob (Drupal)

```
function drupal_cron()
 {
   $cluster = new CouchbaseCluster("couchbase://localhost");
   $cluster->authenticateAs('Admin', 'password');
   $bucket = $cluster->openBucket("default");
   $query = CouchbaseViewQuery::from('drupal', 'id')->reduce(false)->order(CouchbaseViewQuery::ORDER_DESCENDING);
   var_dump($query); // getting data till here
   $results = $bucket->query($query); // not going past this
   var_dump($results); // no data here
   foreach($results->rows as $row) //not going in the foreach loop because no data in $results
     { 
      $doc_id = $row->id;
      $doc = $bucket->get($doc_id);

      // $doc = json_decode($doc->value);

      $doc = $doc->value;
      if ($doc->drupal_status == 'pending')
        {
          sync_code_here
        }
   }
 }
```

The output of var_dump($query)

```
object(Couchbase\ViewQuery)#108 (3) 
{ 
  ["designDocumentName"]=> string(8) "drupal"
  ["viewName"]=> string(2) "id"
  ["options"]=> array(2)
    {
      ["reduce"]=> string(5) "false"
      ["descending"]=> string(4) "true"
    }
 }
```

Pls help

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to create a new design document called "Drupal" and new View called "id" in Couchbase Server to match and validate this

```
 $query = CouchbaseViewQuery::from('drupal', 'id')->reduce(false)->order(CouchbaseViewQuery::ORDER_DESCENDING);
```

After that it worked like a charm.